# Downgrade php5-cgi using APT on Debian

Tags: php, php5, apt, aptitude, php53

I have lighttpd install with PHP5.4 installed

I need to downgrade it to 5.3.2 (possibly older/newer) but I can't install it

I tried this

`apt-get install php5-cgi=5.3.2`

but it says "E: Version '5.3.2' for 'php5-cgi' was not found"

This is my sources.list

`deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian wheezy main`

I tried changing it to squeeze, then doing apt-get update and installing it, but it installs 5.3.8

Answer (score 0):

Debian does not provide that specific version. You might be able to build a 5.3.2 packages using the 5.3.2 tarball and the debian/ dir from 5.3.8 (with a modified changelog).